# Magento 2.2: how to get out of stock products when managing stock

Tags: magento2, stock, out-of-stock, magento2.2

In one of my blocks I want to get a product collection including items that are out of stock, but the product collection always includes `WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)` if you are managing stock.

I don't want out of stock items to show up in categories and search so I do want to manage stock, but in one instance I want to be able to get the products that are out of stock as well.

I have tried all solutions I could find, including:
`->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'is_in_stock=0')`

and

```
$cond = [
    '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
    '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=0'
];

$cond[] = '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 1';

$collection->joinField(
    'inventory_in_stock',
    'cataloginventory_stock_item',
    'is_in_stock',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '(' . join(') OR (', $cond) . ')'
);
```

But everything is negated by the `WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)` part.

EDIT:
`$collection->getAllIds()` does return the IDs of out of stock products, so I can use that to get the out of stock products via a `ProductRepository::getById`.

Comment: Did you ever find solution on this? I am also facing this issue right now

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue, but got the solution on git hub forum:

I used this code and it's working fine now. It's a trick, but it worked for me

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();
//**applied below process to load disable products with default 'enable' once.
$collection->clear();
$where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart('where');
foreach ($where as $key => $condition)
 {
     if(strpos($condition, 'stock_status_index.stock_status = 1') !== false){
             $updatedWhere[] = '(stock_status_index.stock_status IN (1,0))';
      } else {
              $updatedWhere[] = $condition;
       }    
  }
 $collection->getSelect()->setPart('where', $updatedWhere);
 $collection->load();
```

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13411#issuecomment-361250582

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
     */
    protected $productStatus;

    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $productVisibility;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
        $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }
```

And the Filter should be

**//It will return only out of stock**

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory
                ->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToSort('status', $asc_desc)
                ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'is_in_stock=0')
                ->load();
```

**//It will return other than Out of Stock Items**

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory
                ->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToSort('status', $asc_desc)
                ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'is_in_stock=1')
                ->load();
```

Comment: That doesn't return anything because Magento still adds `WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)` to the end of the query used to load the product collection when managing stock

Answer (score 0):

Here magento2 added this. Feel free to change it

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
        <plugin name="add_stock_information" type="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\AddStockStatusToCollection" />
    </type>
```

You can always disable it in your di.xml using this

`plugin disabled`: To disable a plugin, set this element to `true`. The default value is `false`.
Use this property to disable core or third-party plugins in your `di.xml` file.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#declaring-a-plugin

Here is the file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/AddStockStatusToCollection.php.
```

You can override and remove that.

### EDIT

Even better there is a config option in magento 2.2

> configuration->catalog->inventory->Display out of stock products